# fill_parent with ListFragement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-fragments

I am having problems getting my ListFragment to fill the screen vertically.  It fills fine while the data is loading but but once I call setListShown(true) it shrinks to wrap_content.  I changed the background of fragmentContainer and verified that it is shrinking also.  I'm developing on a phone in 2.3.3.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
            Queues qs = new Queues();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, qs);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

edit:
Here's the full layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/queueHeader"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/queueHeaderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14pt"
            android:text="Queues" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:src="@drawable/inin48" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CCFFFFFF" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/navCallback"
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_margin="6dip"
                android:src="@drawable/phone32" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:text="Callbacks" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/navNews"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dip"
                android:src="@drawable/news32" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:text="News" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/navAbout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dip"
                android:src="@drawable/about32" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:text="About" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/navSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dip"
                android:src="@drawable/settings32" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FF000000"
                android:text="Settings" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I created a layout the first time, but then I can't use setListShown(false).  I saw that there was a bug filed about it when using compatibility with a custom layout.

Comment: I've never used `setListShown`. I do think having a custom layout will work, i.e. LinearLayout with ListView each having height of fill_parent. I think that its worth trying that to see if if solves your problem.

Comment: I did try it and I get this problem: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17096

Comment: You could try setting up LayoutParams to `Fill_Parent` and calling `setLayoutParams` on the ListView.

Comment: I get the same result. I am setting it in onActivityCreated.

getListView().setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

Comment: What do I return as the View?  I have nothing to inflate.

Comment: OK, here's the odd part.  I changed the background color of the LinearLayout at the root to #FFFF0000.  That doesn't change the background color of the bottom of the screen. It still stays gray.  It is like there is nothing there. The background of all the other controls turned Red.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment on `onCreateView`, it was late. I plan to delete a few of my comments btw. I'm not great on layouts but when I had similar problems with a WebView I did manage to get things working by using layout_weight="1" on both my LinearLayout and WebView in order to stretch the view, worth a try.